# Getting an error message while startup the tomcat 9

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, netbeans

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKqPy.png)This is my first effort deploying my own App to a remote tomcat server. I've searched and searched my problem and can't find a solution.I am deploying my web application in tomcat 9, and got this error in highlighted in attachment . Initially i got an error message while starting the tomcat .. help

Comment: Just above the highlighted section in the attachment there is error saying no such method error ,so you should be looking into it first and the highlighted one might go away.

Comment: Thanks Amit. its working here.

Comment: Aryan if my comments helped you please give me some points.